# Showing TimePicker dialog from PreferenceFragment activity

Tags: java, android

Hi!

I want to my application to show a TimePicker dialog when the user clicks on a settings item (Preference). I've already created a DialogFragment that creates a TimePicker dialog, but i'm unable to tie this fragment with a Custom Preference. How could this be done?

Here's the DialogFragment class that needs to be tied together with the Custom Preference:

```
import java.util.Calendar;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.app.TimePickerDialog;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.DialogFragment;
import android.text.format.DateFormat;
import android.widget.TimePicker;

public class MyDialogFragment extends DialogFragment implements TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener {

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Use the current time as the default values for the picker
        final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        int hour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
        int minute = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

        // Create a new instance of TimePickerDialog and return it
        return new TimePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, hour, minute,
                DateFormat.is24HourFormat(getActivity()));
    }

    public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
        // Do something with the time chosen by the user
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hourOfDay);
        calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute);
        calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
        ((OpeningScreen) getActivity()).timerAlert(calendar.getTimeInMillis());

    }
}
```

PS. I've read the android developer's tutorial (http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/settings.html), but that's a bit too confusing for me. Thank you very much for your help!